# removing item from accordion after drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, accordion

I have 4 accordion element on the screen. Users are able to drag and drop elements from one accordion to another. I have managed to implement the drag and drop which works fine. however, after drag an item from one accordion to another, i'd want to delete that particular item from the accordion it has been dragged from.

Code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#employee2" ).accordion();
$( "#employee2 li" ).draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone"

});

 $("#destination").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this); // accordion not work 
        $( this ).find(".destination3").remove(); 
       //  ui.draggable.draggable('disable').appendTo(this);
        //$(ui.draggable).appendTo(this); // accordion work but not clone
        $(".employee2").accordion('refresh');

    }
}).sortable({
  items: "li:not(.destination)",
  sort: function() {
    // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
    // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
  }
});
  $("#destination2").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
        //$(ui.draggable).appendTo(this); // accordion work but not clone
        $(".employee2").accordion('refresh');
    }
}).sortable({
  items: "li:not(.destination2)",
  sort: function() {
    // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
    // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
  }
});
});
```

Each of the items in the accordion are placed like this:

```
<h2><a href="#">E Lower </a></h2>
 <div class = "eu">
      <ul id="destination4" class="accordion4">
        <li>Employee 1</li>    
        <li>Employee 2</li>
        <li>Employee 3</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/s0011568344/4dh1kfjg/4/

Comment: Btw i updated the code, let me know if it is what you are looking for

Comment: did you have look is the below fiddle. is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i looked through your fiddle, it was a bit confusing so what i ended up doing was created a new fiddle with what I think you  want.

I simplified the code quite a bit. Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/weqr581c/2/)

```
$(function () {

    $("#employee, #employee2").accordion();

    $("#destination, #destination2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#destination3, #destination4" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable2"
    }).disableSelection();

});
```